# How to execute a jmeter jmx file from a standard docker container?

Tags: docker, jmeter

I'd like to pull down a standard docker container and then issue it a command that will read and execute a .jmx test file from the current folder (or specified path) and drop the results into the same folder (or another specified path/filename). Bonus points if the stdout from jmeter's console app comes through from the `docker run` command.

I've been looking into this for quite some time and the solutions I've found are way more complex than I'd like. Some require that I create my own dockerfile and build my own image. Others require that I set up a Docker volume first on my machine and then use that as part of the command. Still others want to run fairly lengthy bash shell scripts. I'm running on Windows and would prefer something that just works with the standard docker CLI running in any Windows prompt (it should work from cmd or PowerShell or bash, not just one of these).

My end goal is that I want to test some APIs using jmeter tests that already exist. The APIs are running in another locally running container that I can execute with a path and port. I want to be able to run these tests from any machine without first having to install Java and jmeter.

Comment: Part of the issue with the existing solutions is that running real bash scripts on Windows is non-trivial to enable on a given machine: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-bash-shell-command-line-windows-10